# Swift Compiler Error RealmSwift, Xcode 8.2

Tags: swift3, realm, xcode8.2

I'm seeing an "Argument labels '(iCloudToken:)' do not match any available overloads" in Sync.swift.

```
/// Initialize new credentials using an iCloud account token.
public static func iCloud(token: Token) -> SyncCredentials {
    return SyncCredentials(RLMSyncCredentials(iCloudToken: token))
}
```

Is there a fix for this error?

Answer (score 0):

We renamed that method from `iCloud` to `cloudKit` in the latest version of the API. We realized that our authentication mechanism is a wholly CloudKit-based implementation, so referring to it as iCloud was incorrect.

```
public static func cloudKit(token: Token) -> SyncCredentials {
    return SyncCredentials(RLMSyncCredentials(cloudKitToken: token))
}
```

The documentation will be updated soon to reflect this. Sorry for the confusion!